# In VS code Angular application is compiled successfully ,but in browser recent changes are not there

Tags: angular

I am using visual studio code as my code editor for my angular application. Everything was perfectly fine and suddenly out of no where I am facing the following 2 issues.

> 1. When Command `ng serve` is run in the terminal I am getting `√ Compiled successfully.` message. Then I open the port 4200 and run the application. The application is opened there but the last changes are not reflected there.
> 2. When I do changes in my code and save it, compilation is not happening in the terminal.

Both of the above issues were not there just an hour before. Whatever changes I am doing with my code I am not able to get the view in the browser. Do I need to reinstall the VS code? I have restarted my system ,updated vs code still no change. Please help me out if there is something I am missing

**Detailed information about Visual Studio Code**

```
Version: 1.73.1 (user setup)
Commit: 6261075646f055b99068d3688932416f2346dd3b
Date: 2022-11-09T04:27:29.066Z
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Sandboxed: No
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your browser cache? I would give it a hard refresh (ctrl + f5 in case anyone needs it) just to rule it out. Sometimes its the simplest things that cause the biggest headaches.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you need to reinstall VS Code. Sometimes, the `ng engine` simply gets stuck and needs to be bumped to restore proper functionality.

I'm assuming that you didn't introduce this condition by applying incompatible update(s)/upgrade(s) to your angular modules. If you did, then you'll want to back those out and figure out where the incompatibility occurs.

Barring all that, you should only need to:

1. (Hard) Clear your cache.
2. Stop the application in your terminal/CMD window.
3. Run `ng serve` again.

If that doesn't work, then close all instances of your browser, then go through the above steps again.

At worst, simply reboot your computer.